Warum kann ein Verb am Anfang dieses Hauptsatzes stehen?
Aus einem telc C1 Hochschule Übungstest: https://telc.hu/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/telc_deutsch_c1_hochschule_uebungstest1.pdf
Der Antwort auf Frage 30 des Leserverstehens ist so, dass der Rest des Satzes wie folgt lautet: Dauert der Trend zum längeren Leben jedoch unvermindert an, werden die meisten seit dem Jahr 2000 geborenen sogar ihren 100.
Warum kann das Verb hier am Anfang stehen? Gibt es einen Regel, den ich folgen kann?

The relevant term that I learned on this site is "uneingeleiteter Nebensatz", you can find more examples by searching for it.

Der erste Teil des zitierten Beispiels ist kein Hauptsatz, sondern ein Nebensatz, genauer gesagt eine Form eines Bedingungssatzes oder Konditionalsatzes. Nehmen wir, damit die Struktur besser erkennbar wird, eine etwas vereinfachte Version:

Dauert der Trend jedoch an, werden die meisten ihren 100. Geburtstag erleben.

Das ist äquivalent zu

Falls der Trend jedoch andauert, werden die meisten ihren 100. Geburtstag erleben.

In der zweiten Variante wird die Konditionalität ausgedrückt durch eine Konjunktion ("falls", es hätte auch "wenn", "sofern" etc. sein können). Die Konditionalität kann aber auch durch die sogenannte Verb-Erst-Stellung ausgedrückt werden. Man spricht auch von der V1-Stellung oder von einem Stirnsatz. Und genau das ist in dem Beispiel aus dem Übungstest der Fall.
Ein paar weitere Beispiele:

Wenn ich Hunger habe, koche ich mir etwas zu essen.
Habe ich Hunger, koche ich mir etwas zu essen.


Falls er nicht bald kommt, gehen wir ohne ihn los.
Kommt er nicht bald, gehen wir ohne ihn los.


Sofern Sie die Fotos bis heute Abend vorbeibringen, können wir sie noch abdrucken.
Bringen Sie die Fotos bis heute Abend vorbei, können wir sie noch abdrucken.

Der Bedingungsatz in der Verb-Erst-Stellung nimmt den ersten Platz im dazugehörigen Hauptsatz ein.
Die V1-Stellung gibt es auch in anderen Kontexten, zum Beispiel bei Ja/Nein-Fragen:

Der Hund schläft friedlich. -> Schläft der Hund friedlich?

